# Short story about a school trip in a glitching VR simulation

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember reading (or listening to) a short story about some children (possibly brother and sister) in a virtual setting. I believe it was some kind of school trip to the outdoors. I can't remember if the camping theme was throughout or only a small part of their experience though.

The part I remember most clearly is that they were on a small boat like a raft or canoe and found a way to glitch through to other parts of the simulation.

I would have read this sometime between 2010 and 2016 and get the feeling it was in something like Clarkesworld though I'm by no means certain of that.

EDIT: Oh, it's not *The Veldt* again - but that's what reminded me of it.

Comment: Sounds a bit like one of the animated Matrix bonus features ...